# Multiply two arrays values based on the values on the other values

Tags: php, arrays

From the following array I am trying to multiple the quantity and the price on the condition that itemType is Zo.

```
(
    [customer] => 4
    [itemNo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [itemName] => Array
        (
            [0] => Type A
            [1] => Type B
        )

    [itemType] => Array
        (
            [0] => Zo
            [1] => Ram
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
            [1] => 2000
        )
)
```

Here is what I have tried so far but with no success.

```
$lq = 0;
$total =0;

    for ($i=0;$i<count($_REQUEST['price']);$i++) {
        if(in_array("Ram", $_REQUEST['itemType'])){
                $total += $_REQUEST['price'][$i] * $_REQUEST['quantity'][$i];
        }else{
                $lq += $_REQUEST['quantity'][$i];
        }
    }

echo ($total).'<br>';
echo ($lq);
```

My expected output is:

```
$total = 1000;//Quantity x Price
$lq = 3//Quantity only
```

Comment: this will satisfy always `in_array("Ram", $_REQUEST['itemType'])`, just use `==` in each iteration instead, just like the answer below

Comment: @bma, can your data have multiple items of type `Zo`, or would the input have just one `Zo`?

Comment: @BeetleJuice `$_REQUEST` contains form input, so presumably the user is choosing the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking `itemType` of the same item that you're adding to the total. You're just checking whether **any** of the items have that `itemType`. You're also looking for `Ram`, not `Zo`.

```
if ($_REQUEST['itemType'][$i] == 'Zo') {
    $total += $_REQUEST['price'][$i] * $_REQUEST['quantity'][$i];
} else {
    $lq += $_REQUEST['quantity'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$data = $_REQUEST;
$key = array_search('Zo',$data['itemType']);
$total = $data['quantity'][$key] * $data['price'][$key];//Zo price*qty
$lq = array_sum($data['quantity']) - $data['quantity'][$key];//non-Zo qty
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/vgmD4)

Comment: This won't work if there are more than one `Zo` items.

Comment: True; I'll ask the OP whether that's a possibility with his input

Comment: `$lq` contains the total quantity of all the items that don't have `itemType = Zo`